# Is there a way to know if function is Expression-bodied Member from MethodInfo

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Is there a way to know if the function is Expression bodied from MethodInfo?

Comment: Expression bodied members are just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Probably because it looks like you've mistaken the large richtextbox for an other 'Title' field.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault what richtextbox?

Comment: The one where you're supposed the enter the question details/code.

Comment: you can go and see if its expression bodied or not. very simple :) But i was thinking that somehow if you do this with debugger like forexample looking at line of method or using stack trace. not sure what i am saying !! but just guessing xd

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary No, there is no way to tell without having the original source code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you expect them to be different and why would you care?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I am intercepting functions in assembly and want to ignore Expression bodied as they are trivial functions.

Comment: They are no different form any other "trivial" function not declared with an expression body.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Since it's our code base we can confidently say that only trivial functions will be Expression bodied members.

Comment: Have you considered putting an attribute on the non-trivial functions or using a naming convention rather than filtering out the trivial ones?

Comment: @31eee384 It's near impossible to do that with such large code base and adding the attribute will defeat the purpose of doing it dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on my comment and further @SLAks answer...

Expression bodied members are just syntactic sugar, they compile to the same code. For example, consider this class:

```
public class Blah
{
    public void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); }
    public void Bar() => Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

The generated IL looks like this, other than a `nop` (a side effect of compiling in debug mode), they are identical:

```
Blah.Foo:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello"
IL_0006:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000B:  nop         
IL_000C:  ret         

Blah.Bar:
IL_0000:  ldstr       "Hello"
IL_0005:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000A:  nop         
IL_000B:  ret
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why the `nop` is there?

Comment: It's just because it was compiled without optimisations. Turn them on (i.e. in release mode) and `nop` goes away.

Comment: `nop` usually represent brackets when compiling in debug (this is for debugger use). They get optimzied away in release mode.

Comment: I've edited in a clarification of that.

Answer (score 4):

Expression-bodied members are purely syntactic sugar.
The compiled assembly is completely identical regardless.